# (iOS) Parse + Geo Location Query always nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, geolocation

I am trying to download "events" that are within 50 miles of the current user.

When I use the following Parse Query:

```
 if (self.currentLocation == nil) {
        NSLog(@" location is nil");
    }else{

  PFGeoPoint *geoPoint = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLocation:self.currentLocation];

    PFQuery *query = [Post query];
        [query whereKey:@"locationGeoPoint" nearGeoPoint:geoPoint withinMiles:100.0];
       query.limit = 10;
    [query includeKey:@"postOwner"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *Posts, NSError *error){
        if (!error) {

            self.eventsArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:Posts].mutableCopy;



            [self.tableView reloadData];

        }
    }];
}
```

I have tried within 10 miles, 25 Miles, 50 Miles, 75 Miles and nothing seems to work. It works only when I use the following constraint:

```
 [query whereKey:@"locationGeoPoint" nearGeoPoint:geoPoint];
```

as you can see we're not specifying a mile radius.

I have seen other posts with the same problem but no real solution or definitive answer.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: parse.com backend ihas some tecnical limitations for Geopoints. for withinMiles i always pass in whole numbers.

Comment: @FrantzdyRomain I tried whole numbers and still doesn't work.